# Multiplos textView e quebra de linha se preciso na tela

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Eu criei vários textView dentro de um LinearLayout com orientação horizontal e a intenção era de que esses textViews ao chegar no final da linha, fossem para baixo enão foram. Me ajudem a saber como faço isso acontecer.
[A ideia seria que se comportassem assim.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL2Tn.png)

[Mas o que aconteceu foi isso.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szL4n.png)

Segue o código:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_pink"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="1231244"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_pink"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="1231244"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_pink"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="1231244"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -3):

Tente definir o `android:layout_width` dos seus `TextViews` como `0dp`, desta forma:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_pink"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="1231244"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema...

Comment: Olá AMigo!
Não resolveu, pois da forma em que mencionou, os textViews vão se espremendo e não passa pra linha de baixo.